# Identifying which files to edit when using php based CMS

Tags: php

I'm trying to make some edits to a website. The website is based on a CMS and runs on PHP.

I have some html/css experience and have a thick guide to PHP into book to help me.

Among the many edits I'd like to make to the site which are out of the control from the CMS admin area, I'd like to add a Facebook link in the main nav.

Now, I would normally, if inheriting someone else's simpe HTMl/CSS site just use the inspect element feature in Chrome of FF and then see whereabout to edit the code.

Probably a classic rookie question but how does one do that with PHP? If I right click the nav on my site, how do I know which PHP file to edit? Is there a "best way" here?

Here's the site incidentally if it helps at all. I'd like to add (among many other things) a Facebook icon next to the RSS icon in the main nav. I just don't know which file to edit.

http://tinyurl.com/byal33m

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on which CMS you are using.  It's like asking - I have a 'word processor', how do I add an image...

You should read the documentation that comes with the CMS that you are using.  It will likely explain where the files are.

Typically, CMSs usually have a core directory with contain the files that make the CMS work itself, which you wont need to edit.

Then there is a themes directory which contains the files that make up the HTML that is actually rendered and supplemented with data from the CMS.  In the admin area, it usually tells you which theme you are using and where it is located.

Wordpress is a popular CMS, and their documentation explains the basics: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

-- Updated

Question relates to Ushahidi CMS which has documentation indicating theme HTML located in the 'themes' subdirectory.

https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Themes+-+Developers+Guide#Themes-DevelopersGuide-HowdoIinstallatheme%3F

Comment: Thanks for the info Simbolo. It's a less well known CMS called Ushahidi and I have read up on it a fair bit. I guess you've answered the "bigger" question which is "Is there a way, on any PHP site (CMS or not) to identify the file that contains the html you wish to edit?" For example by using the "inspect element" feature?

Comment: There isn't a specific method as such apart from manual file-by-file.  Or you can do a text search and search in files.  For example, search '<body' in the directory holding the files to find matching files that contain the HTML body tag, will be a good start to work from there.  The files are usually always in the same folder.  It's trial an error.  When you find a file, see how it compares, add a HTML comment to see if it shows up in the website etc.  Good luck.

Comment: By the way ,the Ushahidi website does contain documentation detailing where the HTML is stored, in the 'themes' folder see https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Themes+-+Developers+Guide#Themes-DevelopersGuide-HowdoIinstallatheme%3F